# Javascript error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript

What is wrong with the following ??

```
var signup_data = "{'ut': 'T','fn': 'Roy','ln': 'M J','el': 'roy.mj@experionglobal.com','dob': '1988-12-05','pd': '123','did': '3456789-fghjkl','dt': 'I','dtn': 'EA2B6A87-2145-4BA2','ky': 'MTIOS','av': '1.0','gr': 'F','rs': 1,'str': 'street','cy': 'city','st': 1,'co': 1,'zc': '895545','se': 'test@test.com','ph1': '2587456874','ph2': 5874587558'}";
```

Im gettting an  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL in the browser error console.. Im trying to send this as a string instead of json.

Comment: Instead of JSON? That's not JSON.

Comment: Questions about syntax errors are typically not useful to others, just look at the sidebar and see all the duplicate titles. Debug your code, character by character, line  by line. It's a matter of patience really...

Comment: Okay got it working finally.. There was a space in between. The space may have got removed when i formatted in stackvover reply box..:(... Thanks guys..

Comment: i voted up the answer by elclanrs... Thats the anwser..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the last '

```
'}";
```

Make it like this...

```
var signup_data = "{'ut': 'T','fn': 'Roy','ln': 'M J','el': 'roy.mj@experionglobal.com','dob': '1988-12-05','pd': '123','did': '3456789-fghjkl','dt': 'I','dtn': 'EA2B6A87-2145-4BA2','ky': 'MTIOS','av': '1.0','gr': 'F','rs': 1,'str': 'street','cy': 'city','st': 1,'co': 1,'zc': '895545','se': 'test@test.com','ph1': '2587456874','ph2': 5874587558}";
```

Comment: the quotes was not the prob.. there was a space in between. I think a numerical value can be sent both within "123" as we as like 123...hmm thanks anyways.. got it working..:)

Comment: If you want a string, then use `'5874587558'`, if you want a number then use `5874587558`, whichever you want, don't use `5874587558'` (which is what you have in the question)